# lsusb doesn't list device names

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb, lsusb

This is what I get from lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c18  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e046  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003  
Bus 003 Device 086: ID 152d:0567  
Bus 003 Device 089: ID 04d9:0461  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
```

I've tried `-v` and `-t` switches, running as `root` and checking if the device id file(`/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids`) exists.

```
Linux *** 4.1.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 3 21:30:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: That appears to be the expected output from `lsusb`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @larsks Well, I have a debian machine 2 feet away that gives me names of the devices too, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103302/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-lsusb-what-are-all-these-linux-foundation-ro

Comment: Same version of lsusb (`lsusb --version`)?

Comment: I've used lsusb for ages, I'm sure it's not a version thing. lsusb (usbutils) 008

Comment: debian is 007-2, Do you think they could remove features upstream for fun? or is it debian adding features the microsoft way?

Comment: Works fine here (same version of `lsusb`, same distro; my kernel is 4.0.7 though)

Comment: I worked the issue out few months ago, there was a trancend thumb drive in the usb.ids file that had wrong indenting. (archlinux issue, other users reported the same problem on #archlinux)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a distribution using BusyBox, this can be caused by that you are using Busybox' `lsusb` rather than the one from usbutils (or at least so it was on my Alpine/postmarketOS installation).

In such cases you can resolve this by installing `usbutils` and using its `lsusb` instead of the one from BusyBox.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. as noted in the last comment(is hidden, i think) it was caused by a typo in the usb.ids file in archlinux. I found it then by just scrolling through.

Comment: @Behrooz Didn't see that, but regardless, I posted this as it might help some people searching for solutions to this issue.